# Laravel 5.2 Application - autosync two mysql databases

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

I have created web application using laravel, now I need to add functionality for users that when there is no internet connection available data must be stored in their local database, and when the system get internet connection than the data should be sync with the live sever. If we have only one client and one sever than I can use master-salve deployment, but here in my case there are more than 1 local clients.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of having two databases you could tweak the front end a little bit to save data in HTML5's `localStorage` in a neat JSON format so when the user reconnects, you could just push the localStorage items with AJAX and iterate through the array of json objects storing them in empty model objects and save them each.

As for old data, you could store their ID's also in the localStorage so you can just update them which you could easily do with `$some_model->update()`

Comment: I got your points. I think if possible for only 1 table data. But in my case what is happening is, user can add/update or process whole application. It simply means more than 1 tables will be modified. So that's why it needed to have two databases.

Comment: Do you mean that users could still navigate through the pages even without connection? If so wouldnt you have problems with the consistency of data caused by other clients getting and changing data?

Comment: yes, let me give you clear idea. Once system is installed in local system having local database and one database is in live server. When user does not having internet connection whatever changes he performs should be store there in local database. And when he get connection the all changes will be sync with live database.

Comment: as you said, this is the main problem that "consistency of data caused by other clients getting and changing data"